# What exactly is std::function<void(int)> doing in this code?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback, std-function

I've recently come across some code for the inorder traversal of a binary search tree which is as follows:

```
void binary_search_tree::inorder_traversal(bst_node *node, std::function<void(int)> callback) {

    if (node == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    inorder_traversal(node->left, callback);
    callback(node->value);
    inorder_traversal(node->right, callback);
}

std::vector<int> binary_search_tree::get_elements_inorder() {
    std::vector<int> elements;

    inorder_traversal(root, [&](int node_value) {
        elements.push_back(node_value);
    });

    return elements;
}
```

From my understanding, the first function recursively traverses the BST inorder, visiting the left, then the node, then the right. The second function then calls this function to add each element to the vector as each node is hit.

My confusion comes from how each value of the node is obtained. Does `callback(node->value)` store each node value somewhere to be used later? I'm not exactly sure about how this works.

Any help would be much appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: The `node->value` obtains the value of the node.  That value is passed to the `callback` which appends it to the local vector of the `get_elements_inorder` caller.

Comment: ```store each node value somewhere to be used later```: It is called "function stack" which then is used in callback to be pushed to elements vector.

Comment: @Eljay How exactly does that work with the recursion. Is the value returned everytime callback(node->value) is hit? Or do the values queue up and then return once the base condition is met?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik ah I see. I assume that function stack is then pushed to the vector once all the recursion completes?

Comment: @AnthonySeager -- The general reason why that callback is used is so that the client can provide their own code to do whatever they want with the node.  This is basically how a generic traversal function for a tree should be written.  What if the client simply wants to output the value, and not store it?  They don't have to rewrite the entire traversal function over again -- all they would do is provide their own callback.

Comment: @AnthonySeager `callback(node->value)` is a function call. It calls the function `callback` with the argument `node->value`. So the next thing to ask yourself is: what does the function `callback` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function has a pretty good description:

> Class template std::function is a general-purpose polymorphic function
> wrapper. Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any
> *CopyConstructible Callable* target -- functions, lambda expressions,
> bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to
> member functions and pointers to data members.

`std::function<void(int)>` stores a function (or similar) that can be called with an `int` argument and which returns nothing. In particular you can store a lambda in it.

Here the `inorder_traversal` function is called with the lambda `[&](int node_value) { elements.push_back(node_value); }` as argument (under the name `callback`).

Then later when `inorder_traversal` calls `callback(node->value);` it effectively calls the code `elements.push_back(node->value)`. Well not exactly, since this only works because the lambda has *captured* `elements` - without that the vector would not be accessible here. But to know more about how that works I suggest that you read up on lambdas - it is a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you! So essentially the lamda function, elements.push_back(node_value) is passed as an argument? That's pretty cool